# Opcua set node value don't write to the server

Tags: python, client-server, plc, opc-ua

Goodmorning,
I have an opcua python client. I need to connect to a server and to write in a specific node in first place a 0, to wait 1 second, and after to write an 1. How can I do that? I attach the code, witch doesn't crash but doesn't produce nothing on the server

```
def avvio_selezione_1(client):
    time.sleep(1)
    dv = ua.DataValue(ua.Variant(0, ua.VariantType.Int32))
    dv.ServerTimestamp = None
    dv.SourceTimestamp = None
    nodo = client.get_node("ns=1;i=68") #nodo per avvio/stop selezione
    nodo.set_value(dv)#ua.DataValue(ua.Variant(0, ua.VariantType.Int32)))
    time.sleep(1)
    dv2 = ua.DataValue(ua.Variant(1, ua.VariantType.Int32))
    dv2.ServerTimestamp = None
    dv2.SourceTimestamp = None
    nodo = client.get_node("ns=1;i=68") #nodo per avvio/stop selezione 
    nodo.set_value(dv2)
    time.sleep(1)
```